# nginx is not proxy passing to my nest app

Tags: nginx, nest, nginx-config, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to configure NGINX to serve my nest app(which is running on docker).

My app is listening on port 3000

The server is amazon linux 2(ec2-user)

The conf file looks like this:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf;
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  <ip.adress>;

      #web
      location / {
           add_header X-yahav $uri; # this gets mounted 
      }

      #api
      location = /api { # this one is never approached
        add_header X-yahav "Api-pass";
        #proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #proxy_set_header  Host       $http_host;
        #proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
      }

    }
}
```

I want to redirect /api to my nest app but it just wont have it i'm getting a simple 404 without the header i'm attaching(as you can see in the conf file)

Another thing is when I go to the root (location /) I do get my header mounted as expected

Any have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add "/api" to your requests, like http://your-server:80/api/